# C# How to check if message queue worked in domain mode programmatically

Tags: c#, msmq

I have a requirement to send authenticated message to a message queue, signing by internal certificate. This requires the MSMQ to work in domain mode.

I have found an API for VB `MSMQApplication.IsDSEnabled`, but I can't find one for C#?

Comment: Why would there be a different API for C# and VB.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [How to determine if MSMQ 2.0 is installed in Workgroup or Directory mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248500), the registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Workgroup` can be used to verify if MSMQ is working in workgroup mode or domain mode.
`MSMQApplication` seems a COM interface, I am not familiar to COM, so I check the registery as a temporary solution.